# How to derive the expectation of Gompertz distribution?

Tags: probability, integration, probability-distributions, expected-value

We are given $$h(t)=\lambda exp(\theta t)$$, h(t) is the harzard function defined in fields of biostatistics. It has relationship with f(t) in the following way:

$$h(t)=\frac{f(t)}{1-F(t)}$$

I have reached the step of finding $$f(t)=\lambda \exp(t/2-2\lambda \exp(t/2)+2\lambda)$$

But I am unable to derive the expectation by using 
$$E(x)=\int tf(t)dt$$

Could someone please show me how to find the expectation of the Gompertz distribution?

Comment: The [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gompertz_distribution) states the mean in terms of the [exponential integral function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral) $\operatorname{Ei}$, can you derive this? In general $\operatorname{Ei}$ has no closed form, and you cannot simplify this expression further.

Answer (score 2):

Substituting $t = \ln u$ and then integrating by parts,
$$\int_0^\infty \lambda t \exp(t - \lambda e^t) \,dt =
-\int_1^\infty d(e^{-\lambda u}) \ln u =
\int_1^\infty \frac {e^{-\lambda u}} u du =
\Gamma(0, \lambda), \\
\int_0^\infty t f(t) dt =
2 e^{2 \lambda} \Gamma(0, 2 \lambda).$$