# Mean Value of Gompertz Distribution

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

In my attempts to answer  [my own question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4309598/what-is-this-lognormal-like-distribution), I wanted to estimate a given distribution with Gompertz Distribution.

I wanted to use mode, median and mean values to estimate $b$ and $\eta$. [These values on Wikipedia are given as](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gompertz_distribution)

$$
mean=\frac{1}{b}e^\eta\Ei(-\eta)\\
mode=\frac{1}{b}\ln(\frac{1}{\eta})\\
median=\frac{1}{b}\ln[\left(\frac{-1}{\eta}\right)\ln(0.5)+1]
$$

My approach is to find $\frac{median}{mod}$ to eliminate $b$.

Define $M=\frac{median}{mode}$

$$
M=\frac{\ln[\left(\frac{-1}{\eta}\right)\ln(0.5)+1]}{\ln(\frac{1}{\eta})}
$$

$$
\left(\frac{1}{\eta}\right)^M=\frac{-1}{\eta}\ln(0.5)+1.
$$

I thought this is as clean as it gets and solved it for $\eta$ with python. Later, I used the mean value to get $b$ as

$$
b=\frac{e^\eta\Ei(-\eta)}{mean}.
$$

This results in a negative $b$, which is actually defined positive.

When I disregard mean value and compute $b$ and $\eta$ from mode and median, I get some meaningful results, displayed below. Not the best approximation, but it still resembles the starting distribution.

[image]

I checked [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3125020/how-to-derive-the-expectation-of-gompertz-distribution) but it didn't help.

Where do I go wrong? Is the mean expression for Gompertz distribution wrong on wikipedia?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you obtain a positive solution for $\hat\eta$, then $\hat b$ will also be positive, since $\hat\mu > 0$, and $$\operatorname{Ei}(-\hat\eta) = \int_{v = \hat \eta}^\infty \frac{e^{-v}}{v} \, dv > 0$$ whenever $\hat \eta > 0$.

Comment: The problem was with the definition of $\operatorname{Ei}(\eta)$.  Wikipedia defines it different than [DLMF](https://dlmf.nist.gov/6.2#E5) and of course Python. Thanks!